# What evidence was presented in the Expanse (TV) that Nguyen was working with Errinwright?

Tags: the-expanse-2015

In the TV series specifically, Nguyen's actions (launching the protosoldiers to Mars specifically but more or less his entire story starting with when he takes control of the Agatha King) imply that he knows everything about the protomolecule plans.  I must have missed when it became clear that he was privy to those plans.

In the first season or two he just seemed like someone interested in having a war and thus supported Errinwright, but I his final actions seemed to imply that he knew everything.  When did that happen, and when was it revealed in the show?

If I understand it, the books do explain this (although I haven't read them), but they are sufficiently different from the series that I'd prefer series-only answers.

Comment: Gosh, now I'm trying to remember.  I browsed through some episode recaps, and it makes me think it might have been season 3 episode 3 https://blacknerdproblems.com/the-expanse-recap-assured-destruction/  where he was being kinda fishy, and the audience was supposed to suspect then.

Comment: @Kai: I suppose the actor pulls it off well and it's not **really** a surprise, but I was wondering, basically, how he knew how to do all of that and when we are told